# Returning an Index of a Min value in Array Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, find

I'm trying to find an index of the minimum value from sum(3) array. And it should be assigned to a variable *min*

min = *index of minimum value*

Should I sort the array first or is there any direct way of doing it?
Here is my code:

```
 `Sub Min_index()
        Dim Pt_array(3) As Single
        Pt_array(0) = 0
        Pt_array(1) = 12.3
        Pt_array(2) = 16.06
        Pt_array(3) = 20.11

        Dim Ad_E_array(3) As Single
        Dim Lo_E_array(3) As Single
        Dim Bs_temp As Single

        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        Do While i < 4
            Bs_temp = BS
            Ad_E_array(i) = Ad_E    'defined in previous Sub
            Lo_E_array(i) = Lo_E    'defined in previous Sub

            If Bs_temp + Pt_array(i) - Qth < BS_Maximum_limit Then
                Bs_temp = Bs_temp + Pt_array(i) - Qth
                Ad_E_array(i) = Ad_E_array(i) + 0
                Lo_E_array(i) = Lo_E_array(i) + 0
                Call function_decide(int_forecast_hour - 1, Bs_temp, Qth + 1, Lo_E_array(i), Ad_E_array(i))
            Else
                Lo_E_array(i) = Pt_array(i) - Qth - (BS_Maximum_limit - Bs_temp)
                Bs_temp = BS_Maximum_limit
                Call function_decide(int_forecast_hour - 1, Bs_temp, Qth + 1, Lo_E_array(i), Ad_E_array(i))
            End If
        i = i + 1
        Loop

        Dim sum(3) As Single
        Dim min As Single
        i = 0
        Do While i < 4
        sum(i) = Abs(Lo_E_array(i)) + Abs(Ad_E_array(i))
        i = i + 1
        Loop
  End Sub`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can receive the 1-based index position of the element containing the minimum value with the an [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx)'s use of the worksheet's [MIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7) and [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
Sub wqewuiew()
        Dim Pt_array(3) As Single, p As Long
        Pt_array(0) = 1000
        Pt_array(1) = 12.3
        Pt_array(2) = 16.06
        Pt_array(3) = 20.11

        p = Application.Match(Application.Min(Pt_array), Pt_array, 0)

        Debug.Print p   '<~~ 'p' is 2 (I changed the value of the first array element)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped   
It works. 
Can I also get the value (12.3) of index 2?

Comment: Just `Application.Min(Pt_array)` or the more verbose `pt_array(Application.Match(Application.Min(Pt_array), Pt_array, 0)-1)`.